# How to get UTC date in milliseconds format similiar to new Date().getTime() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, utc

To solve a time zone issue which is seen when I deploy my project,I need to convert my current date in millisecond format to corresponding UTC date in milliseconds.How can I solve it?

Comment: When you fill up the date object with a date time value in UTC the returned milliseconds are also in utc. Because the time zone defines an area on the surface of the world. So a time is always bound to a location to be true.

Comment: var d = new Date();
var n = d.getUTCSeconds(); this without DST. If you want to consider DST use momentjs

Comment: @murli2308 .thanks for your effort.But getUTCseconds() returns a number between 0 and 59 and that is not what I require.The long Date format in milliseconds shows the number of milliseconds since January,1970 to the given date

Comment: @AlanVargheseAniyan Use var d = new Date(); var n = new Date(d.toUTCString()).getTime();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying different methods this is what I found to be most efficient and working solution.

```
       var d = new Date(); //d can be any date we need to convert.
       var millisec= d.getTime()+ (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
```

getTimeZoneOffset() returns the offset time in minutes

**EDIT**:

Actually the above code *adds* the offset to the local date (instead of subtracting) and my server (which is UTC) allows to get back the local time on the server.

I need the local time in server, as I realised later, we've local times in the API data that we use.

So coming back to the original question, a possible solution to convert local to UTC would be:

```
       var d = new Date(); //d can be any date we need to convert.
       var millisec= d.getTime() - (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
```

> In another project later I used the below for date in string form:

a. to convert from local to UTC (while sending to server):

```
new Date().toUTCString()
```

b. to convert back to local (while getting data to web from server:

```
date.toLocaleDateString("en-AU", {
                weekday: 'short', year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric',
                hour12: false, hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric'
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

- Here I come with one of the simplest solution to convert our local
  time to UTC milliseconds to save in server.

> ```
> const utcDate = new Date().toUTCString();
> // Mon, 21 Dec 2020 11:13:16 GMT
> ```

- This will print the date as UTC string as above. You can convert it
  as UTC milliseconds by using,

> ```
> const sendToServer = Date.parse(utcDate);  //1608549196000
> ```

- You can convert that UTC milliseconds to your local time by using,

> const myLocalDate = new Date(1608549196000);
> // Tue Dec 22 202000:13:16 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a funcion for that, [getTime()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp):

```
function myFunction() {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getTime();
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a big "can of worms", due to time zones that enter and leave daylight saving time during the year, and then sometimes vary when they do it.

If you don't mind your times potentially being 1 hour wrong then the simplest thing to do is add or subtract the number of milliseconds difference between the timezone you have and UTC. To get it right though I suggest you have a look at the moment-timezone library: http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: I have tried the js date  function getTimezoneOffset() and it was working in my case.Will there be any cases were this may not work?

Comment: That will be fine so long as you always want the time displayed in the user's own local time zone. So 12pm UTC today would show as 8am to a user in Boston and 1pm to a user in Rome. If that's correct for your application, great!

Answer (score -2):

```
var myDate = new Date(); 
var utcDate = myDate.toUTCString();
var milliSec = utcDate.getMilliseconds();
```